# Data Modelling for Big Data

Tags: graph, hive, google-bigquery, arangodb, bigdata

[image]

**I have this type of database to implement**
Circled point are various cities.

People are travelling from one city to another.
Number of people travelling from one city to another are shown by the weight over the edges.

Circle G : is my goal city

**What I want to achieve?**

1. total number of people reaching "G"?
2. What path they followed to reach goal "G"?

**e.g :**

- 200 people started from A->F..!
- 100 goes back to A using Path F->A
- from remaining 100 only 20 user made to reach Goal "G"

so, the number of people reaching "G" from the right side is 80

**What information I need at point “G”**

- `80 people from right side = 20(from A->F->G) + 60 (from A->D->F->G)`

This is a small graph. 
**I want to implement this on a graph having 1000+ Nodes**?

Right now the **approach I am taking** to solve this is (**using ArangoDB**) :

- I am creating One Vertex collection and One Edge collection.
- Each City (A, B, C, D) is document inside same collection.
- I am saving the complete previous path for every people travelling.

**e.g John is travelling from A->G**

- The details I am saving at F for John: {"John : A_D_F"}
- The details I am saving at city G for John: {"John : A_D_F_G"}
- I am repeating this for Every single people travelling.

**In short I want to achieve funneling at Any point(city) in the graph.**

What is the better way of data modelling for this type of graph in Arango or other Big Data Storage and which Big Data Storage will be best?

Thanks..!

Comment: It looks to me that the data in your example is not enough to compute paths. I.e. how do you know that 100 people that went F->A are from 200 who went A->F and not from those who went D->F

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky Yes u are somewhat right but in real scenario, it is like there are 300 people at city "F' and 100 amongst them went back to city "A". These people can be from both path in real scenario (A->F, A->D->F).

Ok..! for simplicity for now let's  assume the same graph but this time acyclic and unidirectional (i.e flow downwards)..., then How to model this type of data and what tool is perfect for solving these problems..? Thanks..!

Comment: @MoshaPasumansky let's also consider people going back (F->A) are dead people(or churned out..)

Comment: Can this http://faculty.cas.usf.edu/mbrannick/regression/Pathan.html  help me solving the above problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in your conclusion to treat this a graph problem. Irrespective of the tech stack that you want to use, I suggest you model your data by following some of the best practices/examples outlined in these links

https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-data-modeling/

https://www.infoq.com/articles/data-modeling-graph-databases

There are a lot of proven choices with reference to scaling to a 1000 or even 10000 node graph

**Here is one possible way to model this:**

a] Treat the Cities and Persons as Nodes

b] Then model the City-to-City path as Relationships

c] Also then add the Person-has-travelled-to-City as a Relationship

d] If you need to sequence the relationship you can use Properties on the Person-to-City relationship

**Next step is to**

Create these in a Graphdb of your choice

Create the Sample Dataset

Run your queries and check the answers

See if you need to optimize either the model or the Data

Hope this helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.